# Understanding map() with global variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to learn more about the `map()` function and if I can use it to speed up iteration over massive lists in my other programs. Right now im trying to understand the output of the following code:

```
x = []
for y in range(1000):
    x.append(0)
print(x[0])

def func(y):
    global x
    x[y] += 1

for y in range(100):
    func(y)

print(x[0])

map(func, range(100))

print(x[0])
```

output:

```
0
1
1
```

Why is the output not

```
0
1
2
```

and what modifications would I need to make to the above code to achieve this output?

My interest is largely academic. Any information or direction to a good source is appreciated.

Comment: python 3: map doesn't even run. Don"t use map for side effects.